# NETLOGO: turtles-own lists too big for GUI

Tags: list, netlogo

In Netlogo, I have turtles-own lists, which means I set a turtle's variable to be a list. Each tick, another value is added to the list. After a few thousand ticks, these lists are quite long... and the problem arises that I can't open the agent monitor in the GUI any more because it takes too long to load the list.

reproducible code:

```
breed [persons person]
turtles-own [examplelist]

to setup
   clear-all
   reset-ticks    
   create-persons 1 [setxy 0 0]
   ask turtles [set examplelist []]
end

to go
   ask turtles [set examplelist lput ticks examplelist]
   tick
end
```

I would need the agent monitor to watch another turtle-own variable; I don't need to watch the lists (they are just used to do a calculation every 8760 ticks). 
Is there maybe a possibility, to e.g. hide the list from the agent monitor? Or do I need to handle the lists as global variables instead? Being quite unhandy as I would need to create and name separate lists for every turtle...

Comment: what is the calculation that is done every 8760 ticks? it it's something like a sum, max or average, you could keep a running value instead of all the items that go into the calculation?

Comment: Unfortunately, I did not want to define the calculation at this stage. I want to create a modelling framework for water managers, where the turtles are different water users. The water users can experience water scarcity every tick (=day) or not, whereby the extent of the scarcity is stored in the list. And then, the water users can simulate if every year (8760 ticks), or 5 years, or 10 years they can look at the scarcities and pick out decision variables, which could be EITHER the maximum or a mean or a median or whatever; and change something in the water distribution concept.

Comment: My idea would have been, that this code section (the calculation of the scarcity and the creation of the "scarcity list") is kept constant for every case study / application.... And only the other, code section, where it is defined what to do with the scarcity list, which variables to pick out, can be modified according to the peculiarities of the case studies.

Answer (score 3):

I can see three options:

1/ If you are creating a modelling framework, I assume that your user cannot actually code in NetLogo. This means that you have to predefine the scenarios for them anyway (for example, they could choose the calculation), so you only need to have the possible calculations stored instead of all the input values to those calculations.

2/ It is not clear from your question why any user would open an inspect window or otherwise access the individual turtle. If the user doesn't need it directly, instead of adding all this information to the turtles, you could export it to a file, adding a line each tick. The user would do the analysis of the simulation in R or Excel or whatever.

3/ You could create a shadow turtle for every turtle. This is not something I would recommend, but the idea is that the shadow turtle has a subset of variables (not the lists) and the variable values it does have are identical to the turtle it is shadowing. The limited set of variables version of the turtle is the one that would accessible to monitor.